# How should a SPDT switch be wired for a digital input?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, input, toggle-switch

I want to connect a switch to a digital input on a logic board and make it so that the input goes high when the switch is pressed. I'll be using a SPDT switch:

[image]

Should I connect the digital input to COM, GND to NC, and VCC to NO?

*Or* could I connect VCC to COM and the digital input to NO? (this would leave the digital input "floating" when the switch isn't pressed, but is that necessarily a bad thing?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the first option: connect the digital input on the micrcontroller to COM, GND to NC (1T), and VCC to NO (2T), except use an resistor, e.g. 4.7K, between VCC and the NO (2T) terminal.  Usually not a good idea to connect VCC directly to an input pin on the micrcontroller -- for example, if it became a digital output for some reason and was at GND level, you would have a nasty short.

Answer (score 3):

I would connect it thus:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu7pew.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor will pull the input high when the switch is pressed.

Comment: Except that this circuit would require debouncing.

Comment: debouncing is a minor software function :-)

Answer (score 1):

Connect a series resistor 4k7 from the digital input pin to the COM 1P.

Connect a series resistor 1k from VCC to NO 2T.

Connect NC to GND.

The first series resistor protects the digital input if it can be configured as an output; it may drive to VCC or GND.  Omit if it cannot be reconfigured.  Omit if the logic board already has a series resistor on the digital input.

The second series resistor protects the supply from a fault that may develop in the switch, a fault which shorts NO to NC.

The capacitance of the digital input pin will cause the existing voltage level to remain while the switch is being moved.  Obviating debouncing.

However, if the logic board digital input has a pullup or pulldown resistor, you must either add capacitance to defeat it, or code for debouncing.

All this uncertainty might be cleared up by describing the digital input more thoroughly.  ;-)